# google_authenticator ownership automatically changes to root on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions, login, pam

Running Ubuntu 18.04 Server, it seems pam will change the ownership of `~/.google_authenticator` on login to root:USER

This means next time I try to login, I will be rejected. Changing the ownership of `~/.google_authenticator` to USER:USER enables login again. Logging in with public key does not change the ownership.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was not pam or google_authenticator that was the problem. My nfs mounted home directory got an updated configuration when upgrading to 18.04 that mapped all users to root.